# How to update SPFx web part property pane values using PowerShell scripts?

Tags: powershell, spfx, spfx-webparts, 2019, spfx-custom-property-pane

How to update SPFx web part configuration property pane values in SharePoint 2019 on premises site using PowerShell?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Check this & let me know if it helps: https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2013/08/update-web-part-properties-programmatically.html